# Counting the number of elements in array

Tags: twig

I am looking to count the number of entries I have in an array in Twig. This is the code I've tried:

```
{%for nc in notcount%}
{{ nc|length }}
{%endfor%}
```

This however only produces the length of the string of one of the values in the array.

`{{nc}}` will produce an output of all the values of the array (there are 2) but I want the output to be just the number 2 (the count) and not all the information in the array.

Answer (score 175, accepted):

Just use the [length filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/length.html) on the whole array. It works on more than just strings:

```
{{ notcount|length }}
```

Comment: If `notcount` is not an array, but an object of a class implementing SPL Countable interface (this is the case of, for example, Doctrine's `\Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection`), you can use `{{ notcount.count }}`

Answer (score 6):

This expands on the answer by Denis Bubnov.

I used this to find child values of array elements—namely if there was a anchor field in paragraphs on a Drupal 8 site to build a table of contents.

```
{% set count = 0 %}
{% for anchor in items %}
    {% if anchor.content['#paragraph'].field_anchor_link.0.value %}
        {% set count = count + 1 %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% if count > 0 %}
 ---  build the toc here --
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 5):

Best practice of getting length is use [`length`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/length.html) filter returns the number of items of a sequence or mapping, or the length of a string. For example: `{{ notcount | length }}`

But you can calculate count of elements in [`for`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html) loop. For example:

```
{% set count = 0 %}
{% for nc in notcount %}
    {% set count = count + 1 %}
{% endfor %}

{{ count }}
```

This solution helps if you want to calculate count of elements by condition, for example you have a property `name` inside object and you want to calculate count of objects with not empty names:

```
{% set countNotEmpty = 0 %}
{% for nc in notcount if nc.name %}
    {% set countNotEmpty = countNotEmpty + 1 %}
{% endfor %}

{{ countNotEmpty }}
```

Useful links:

- [`length`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/length.html)
- [`set`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/set.html)
- [`for`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
{%for nc in notcount%}
{{ loop.index }}
{%endfor%}
```

**loop.index -- The current iteration of the loop.**

for reference:https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html